# Java Form and Subform

Tags: java, swing

I've got a parent form and a sub-form for my application. Now, in my button handler to open the sub form, I have the following code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        SubForm test = new SubForm();
        Author retriveAuthor = null;
        test.setVisible(true);
        retriveAuthor = test.getAuthor();
        jTextField3.setText(retriveAuthor.getFirstName());
}
```

Sub form:

```
    Author subCreateAuthor;

   public SubForm() {
       initComponents();
   }

   public Author getAuthor()
   {
       return this.subCreateAuthor;
   }

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     // TODO add your handling code here: 
    //When the user clicks the button Create Author it will 
    //grab the text from the two text boxes and then create the author object.
    //Afterward it will set the form visible parameter to false.
    subCreateAuthor = new Author(jTextField1.getText(),jTextField2.getText());
    this.setVisible(false);
 }
```

My problem is, when I call the **sub-form** the **parent form** doesn't wait until the **sub-form** is closed, it attempts the set the text of jtextfield3, however, it throws a nullpointerexception because the retrieveAuthor object isn't fully created yet. How would I properly call my subform and then when the form is closed set the jTextField with my Author object?

I attempted to set the sub-form visibility to false and then check it in my main form, but that didn't work.

Comment: What kind of class is your subform? It has to be a modal dialog for this logic to work, or it can be a JPanel displayed in a JOptionPane.

Comment: @FredK - Same as my parent form. Both are JFrames

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/666115/GUI/java/Creating-Java-Forms-Subforms. Quit cross posting, you already have an answer. It is annoying when people spend time answering a question that has already been answered.

Comment: @camickr - what does it matter if I posted the question in two different places. CR and SO have nothing to with each other.

Comment: @user6382783, I just told you. Our time is valuable. We don't have time to spend answering questions that already have an answer. We would rather spend our time helping people who don't have answer to their questions.

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) (in particular, modal dialogs)